# Groovy Mixins - Class.mixin()/MetaClass.mixin() or Traits?

Tags: groovy, traits, mixins

In the Groovy doc it mentions that the @Mixin annotation was deprecated in favor of traits. However, aside from traits, there's also Class.mixin() and MetaClass.mixin() functionality. For mixin semantics what's preferred or more idiomatic? Or am I missing the point such that *.mixin() and Traits are completely different concepts, (but with some similarities)?

Comment: May be this gives you what you want - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdBkw9TU_u4

Comment: 17:23 -- "Mixins are often a runtime mechanism where traits are often a compile-time mechanism, so you can use mixin and trait kind of interchangeably"